# How to get path in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get this path (arrow on image)?

[image]

```
await this.$fire.firestore.collection('saveups').doc(INSERT_DOC_PATH_HERE).set({
    bill: payload
  })
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you replace the `INSERT_DOC_PATH_HERE` with the "PLpG..." string that should work. If you don't know that value (known as the document ID), what **do** you know that uniquely identifies the document that you want to update?

Comment: I know only this id. So how can I get this id from firebase? I wanna receive this id and place it as a value

Comment: @LevVorobev Just replace `INSERT_DOC_PATH_HERE` by the id of the document.

Comment: how to get id of the doc?

Comment: You should revise what you're asking by asking yourself; WHY do you want to get that document - what makes is 'special' compared to the other ones. Is it because it has a child property title with 'mona' as the value? Or something else. Once you can express WHY you want that specific document, you can then create a query that will return that document as snapshot where the documentID will be the `PLpGx...`

Answer (score 1):

To find the correct document id, you must query for it using known and expected variables, such as:

```js
 this.$fire.firestore.collection('saveups').where("bill" ,"<",0).get();
```

alternatively, you can get all documents with a limit

```js
 this.$fire.firestore.collection('saveups').limit(3).get();
```

This kind of operation is also done by referencing the document in other documents to complete a 'flow' of data. you can read more about Firestore Reads [**here**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).

Answer (score -1):

Solution is where I get a record, I also get document ID and save it into this record

```
const getData = await this.$store.dispatch('saveups/getSaveups').then(s => {
  s.docs.forEach(doc => {
    const result = Object.assign({id: doc.id}, doc.data()) //here
    this.goals.push(result)
  })
})
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.